# Restore text messages from Google Messages to new iPhone (Android phone is bricked)

Tags: iphone, messages, restore, android, google-apps

How can I restore my text messages backup from the Google Messages app into my new iPhone?

I know there's a move to iOS app, which is great if your old phone is functional. Problem is my Pixel 4 spontaneously self-bricked overnight and I can't figure out how to restore my text message backup from Google Drive into my iPhone.

I have seen lots of resources on restoring the backup to an Android phone, and transferring text messages from a working Android phone to an iPhone, but I can't seem to find a way to restore a backup directly.

Note: I have verified that a backup for 12/17/2021 exists in Google Drive, but I don't see any way to recover it.

Comment: Have you downloaded the [Google Chat](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/google-chat/id1163852619) app from the Apple Store to see if you can open the backup on Google Drive? I use it as part of my Enterprise chat in our GApps for Education suite.

Comment: yes, that's a chat app (modern replacement for the once pervasive aol messenger). I use it as well, but it doesn't seem to provide any sms backup/restore capability

Comment: AFAIK, backups on Google Drive can only be accessed and restored on Android. Other than a real Android device, you probably need to set up an Android emulator/VM to restore it first.